# How to generate unique id from the loop

Tags: xml, xslt, key, uniqueidentifier

I have two elements i have to pick a unique out of it while looping am using key but am getting empty instead of one. Please see below

```
 <xsl:key name="Keyunique"  match="//schedules/test/Operatorvalue" use="//schedules/test/Operatorvalue/@Operatorvalue" />



<xsl:template name="Buildairline">        
        <xsl:for-each select="//schedules/test">    
          <xsl:for-each select="key('Keyunique', //schedules/test/Operatorvalue/@Operatorvalue)[1]">                
            <Row Action="ADD">
              <xsl:value-of select="current()/Operatorvalue" />|<xsl:value-of select="current()/OperatorDesc" />|test|<xsl:value-of  select="current()/operatordesc2" />
            </Row>              
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Rows>       
  </xsl:template>
```

Below is the xml

```
<schedules>
<test>
<Operatorvalue>value1</Operatorvalue>
<OperatorDesc>valuedesc</OperatorDesc>
<OperatorDesc2>valuedesc2</OperatorDesc2>
</test>
<test>
<Operatorvalue>value1</Operatorvalue>
<OperatorDesc>valuedesc</OperatorDesc>
<OperatorDesc2>valuedesc2</OperatorDesc2>
</test>
<test>
<Operatorvalue>value2</Operatorvalue>
<OperatorDesc>valuedesc2</OperatorDesc>
<OperatorDesc2>valuedesc3</OperatorDesc2>
</test>
<schedules>
```

Expected output

```
Row value1|valuedesc|valuedesc2
Row value2|valuedesc2|valuedesc3
```

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues, among them:

1. you have a named template that is never *called* - and apparently no other templates that are *applied*;
2. your implementation of *Muenchian grouping* is incorrect;
3. you are using `//` in places where you need a *relative* path to the descendants of the current node; `//` always starts at the root;
4. XML is case-sensitive: `operatordesc2` does not select a node named `Operatordesc2`;
5. `Operatorvalue` is an *element*, not an *attribute* - so `@Operatorvalue` will not select anything.

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="Keyunique" match="test" use="Operatorvalue"/>

<xsl:template match="/schedules">    
    <xsl:for-each select="test[generate-id()=generate-id(key('Keyunique', Operatorvalue)[1])]">     
        <xsl:text>Row </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Operatorvalue" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="OperatorDesc" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="OperatorDesc2" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example (after closing the `schedules` tag!), the result will be:

```
Row value1|valuedesc|valuedesc2
Row value2|valuedesc2|valuedesc3
```

Note that the values of `OperatorDesc` and `Operatordesc2` are taken **only** from the **first** record in each group .